# Corda database connection with SQL Server 17 failed

Tags: corda

Facing this error when trying to connect Corda  v3.3 to SQL server 2017.

```
 Could not find method dataSourceProperties() for arguments [build_b58g7zpxmgi2o4qynsvg23rrl$_run_closure7$_closure18$_closure22@6e5d745d] on object of type
net.corda.plugins.Node.
```

deployNodes code snippet is

```
dataSourceProperties {
        dataSourceClassName ("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource")
        dataSource.url  ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb")
        dataSource.user (testuser)
        dataSource.password  (123)
    }
    database {
        transactionIsolationLevel (READ_COMMITTED)

    }
    jarDirs = [".../Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the syntax of `deployNodes` with the syntax of the `node.conf` node configuration file.

If you want to add additional configuration options in `deployNodes` that will be copied to the node's `node.conf` file, you need to use `extraConfig`, as follows:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10007
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10008")
            adminAddress("localhost:10048")
        }
        cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        extraConfig = [
                dataSourceProperties: [
                        dataSourceClassName: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource',
                        dataSource         : [
                                url     : 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb',
                                user    : 'testuser',
                                password: '123'
                    ]
                ],
                database            : [transactionIsolationLevel: 'READ_COMMITTED'],
                jarDirs             : ['.../Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/']
        ]
    }
}
```